# android gridview image setting visibility

Tags: android, android-gridview

In my android application .i have gridview. in that after performing operation on one of the select item of grid view i want to set visibility of that item false.how to do this?

code is below-

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int no,long lg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                id=no;
                alert.setTitle("Title");
                alert.setMessage("Message");
                alert.setIcon(flag[no]);

                // Set an EditText view to get user input 
                final EditText input = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
                alert.setView(input);

                alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                  String value = input.getText().toString();
                  // Do something with value!
                  System.out.println("mmmm"+value);
                  if(value.equalsIgnoreCase(country[id])){

                                 // here i want to set item visibility..

                  }
                  else
                    {}
                  }
                });

                alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    // Canceled.
                  }
                });

                alert.show();
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot hide a single item in gridView

The only thing you can do is changing the list of items passed to gridView adapter. you can remove the item to be hidden from your list and call notifyDataSetChanged to make the gridView reflect your change.

Comment: another way is using checkbox for that purpose.how to use checkbox.??how can i add check box for every image in grid view???

Comment: Use custom gridView Adapter and you can add you custom layout for each item of gridView